# Hibernate Model class and DAO

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate3

I have a simple question and I hope I can find answer here!
Can we mix hibernate model and DAO in same class?
Is there a design Pattern which specify this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're referring to [ActiveRecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) pattern, there the model class has methods to save(), get(), etc. This pattern is implemented in frameworks like Django and Ruby n' Rails.
Hibernate uses [Data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern instead.